# Is there a pip freeze equivalent for Node and NPM?

Tags: node.js, npm

This is idiomatic in Python:

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

The first command saves a list of requirements to a file. Then later you can use the command to install the requirements into your environment.

Node has `npm install`, but I don't get how to I'm supposed to dump the state of my dependencies to a package.json. I Googled and found [this](https://gist.github.com/ChimeraCoder/3152820):

```
npm ls | grep -E "^(├|└)─" | cut -d" " -f2 | awk '{FS = "@"; print "\""$1"\"", ":", "\""$2"\""}'
```

but as the author of this pipeline suggests, there's got to be a better way? What am I missing here?

I just want to dump my current deps into a package.json. As https://npmjs.org/doc/shrinkwrap.html says,

> The "package.json" file is still required if you want to use "npm install".

I've skimmed the info on `shrinkwrap`, but I'm not seeing how to simply accomplish this task with `shrinkwrap`.

Comment: For anyone reading this in 2021 and beyond, npm/yarn now have lock files that accomplish this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be built into NPM versions 6+ via the `package-lock.json`
https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/configuring-npm/package-lock-json

Comment: Yep. This should be the accepted answer these days. And similarly yarn.lock for yarn users.

Answer (score 20):

This is the closest I got

#### npm freezelol

`npm ls | grep -E "^(├|└)─" | cut -d" " -f2 | awk -v quote='"' 'BEGIN { FS = "@" } ; { print quote $1 quote,":",quote $2 quote"," }' | sed -e 's/ :/:/g'`

Output is like

```
  "bower": "1.3.12",
  "chai": "2.1.2",
  "cucumber": "0.4.8",
```

Still needs to trim the final trailing comma but it's pretty close!

Comment: @JohanLAJILIlajili.com yes!

Comment: Enhanced version of above command to generate dependencies and devDependencies section separately:  [npm-freeze](https://gist.github.com/nagapavan/22070c34522d15c072b7c258c09cb4ce)

Comment: @kn_pavan how to run this `npm-freeze`?

Comment: Add the function to a shell script and source it from terminal. And call npm-freeze at the root of the project

Answer (score 14):

You can create a package.json out of the currently installed package using [`npm init`](https://npmjs.org/doc/cli/init.html). Then you can easily move the package.json and simply do `npm install` to install the packages wherever you want.

Comment: And how to update package.json if packages where installed without `--save` or `--save-dev` switch?

Comment: You can add them manually or run `npm update` / `install` with save options. Note the version you give (or the latest one if you don't give version) goes into the json as the dependency.

Comment: I meant, how to update it automatically :P — I know I can edit files ;)

Comment: @JanuszSkonieczny did you find any way?

Answer (score 12):

This will probably work for you. [npm shrinkwrap](https://www.npmjs.org/doc/cli/npm-shrinkwrap.html)

```
npm shrinkwrap
```

Comment: A bit too aggressive in locking down dependencies recursively (`npm init` doesn't do this) for a casual context, but thanks that is useful.

Comment: yeah, i usually go through and remove the dependencies of the dependencies, really should be a flag on the command.

Comment: `npm init` worked for me, and picked up the existing dependencies (from the `node_modules` folder)

Comment: This answer seems incomplete. The original question stated that he "skimmed the info on shrinkwrap". The problem is *not* only that of freezing dependencies, but that npm actually needs both package.json and the shrinkwrap. Somewhere this answer should include `npm init` for the package.json part of the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Here is alternative shorter version of command which parses `npm ls`:

```
npm ls | grep -o "\S\+@\S\+$" | tr @ ' ' | awk -v q='"' '{print q$1q": "q"^"$2q","}'
```

And here is an alias which is worth to add to your shell *rc* file:

```
alias npm-freeze='npm ls | grep -o "\S\+@\S\+$" | tr @ " " | awk -v q='\''"'\'' '\''{print q$1q": "q"^"$2q","}'\'''
```

and run it as:

```
npm-freeze
```

The output is like:

```
"backbone": "^1.3.2",
"underscore": "^1.8.3",
"bootstrap": "^3.3.6",
"bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.6",
"grunt": "^0.4.5",
```

To filter, just pipe it into `grep`, e.g.

```
$ npm-freeze | grep grunt
"grunt": "^0.4.5",
"grunt-cli": "^0.1.13",
"grunt-contrib-watch": "^0.6.1",
"grunt-sass": "^1.1.0",
"load-grunt-tasks": "^3.4.1",
```

---

Here is the example saving the output into `package.json` and running `npm install`:

```
printf "{\n"\""name"\"": "\""npm-freeze"\"",\n"\""dependencies"\"": {\n$(npm-freeze | grep grunt | head -c -2)\n}\n}" | tee package.json && npm install
```